# Create custom calculated column in Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

So I have a pivot table with automated speed test results (flattened to csv [here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/b88d605e60934d78fca49e2d396bfeb5/Book2.csv); not pasted in the question to keep it clean). The table has measured times in milliseconds per step, per test type and test iteration (see notes [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAk85.png)).

The data comes from a CSV file which I copy over to a tab in my Excel workbook and reference in my pivot table. The columns (Step A, Step B,  ...) come from the CSV file (and are output by my NUnit test suite), and are, as such, dynamic.

What I would like to do is add a calculated **column** to my dynamic columns with a `sum` of other columns. For example, I might want to have an extra column between Step B and Step C, with the `sum` of *Step A* and *Step B*. Additionally, I want a average of that calculated column in my *Grand Totals* row at the bottom. What calculated columns I'm going to need (itself) is not going to change.

How would I go about achieving this?

*Note: I have found many questions about calculated **fields**. However, that doesn't seem to solve my problem.*